# How do i get number of same relationships between two nodes with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

Now I need query that returns ancestor nodes of Borko with number of relationship hops.. Something like this:

- Cupko ...  1
- Mirko ...  2
- Jan   ...  3

2nd part of question : If we include mother relationships, what would query look like? result should be something like:

- Cupko ... dad ... 1
- SomeFemale ... mom ... 1
- Mirko ... dad ... 2
- SomeFemale2 ... mom ... 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this snippet to recreate your data set:

```
CREATE
   (:Person {name: 'Jan'})-[:Father]->
   (:Person {name: 'Mirko'})-[:Father]->
   (:Person {name: 'Cupko'})-[:Father]->
   (:Person {name: 'Borko'})
```

You should save the [path](https://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html) and use the length of path to get the number of hops:

```
MATCH p=(b:Person {name: 'Borko'})<-[:Father*]-(n)
RETURN n, length(p)
```

This returns:

```
╒════════════════╤═══════════╕
│"n"             │"length(p)"│
╞════════════════╪═══════════╡
│{"name":"Cupko"}│1          │
├────────────────┼───────────┤
│{"name":"Mirko"}│2          │
├────────────────┼───────────┤
│{"name":"Jan"}  │3          │
└────────────────┴───────────┘
```

For the second part, you can use the [`relationships`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-relationships) function:

```
MATCH p=(b:Person {name: 'Borko'})<-[:Father|Mother*]-(n)
WITH p, relationships(p) AS rels, n
RETURN n, length(p) AS hops, type(rels[length(rels)-1]) AS type
```

This returns:

```
╒════════════════╤══════╤════════╕
│"n"             │"hops"│"type"  │
╞════════════════╪══════╪════════╡
│{"name":"Cupko"}│1     │"Father"│
├────────────────┼──────┼────────┤
│{"name":"Mirko"}│2     │"Father"│
├────────────────┼──────┼────────┤
│{"name":"Jan"}  │3     │"Father"│
└────────────────┴──────┴────────┘
```

Of course, you can use case expressions to convert the name of the relationship the appropriate type, e.g. `CASE type(rels[length(rels)-1]) WHEN 'Father' THEN 'Dad' WHEN 'Mother' THEN 'Mom' END AS role`